# How do you determine the records included in Table A and not in Table B

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two SQL (Azure SqlDB) tables, Table A and Table B. Each table share the P_Code column.  Table A has 600 records and Table B has 400 matching (A.P_Code = B.P_Code).

I'm interested in seeing the 200 records in A and not in B. I have tried the following two queries, but neither returns any results.   Where am I going wrong.

```
Select A.* From 
[Table A]A 
FULL OUTER JOIN
[Table B]B
ON A.P_CODE = B.P_CODE
WHERE B.P_CODE IS NULL

Select A.* From 
[TABLE A] A 
LEFT JOIN
[TABLE B] B
ON A.P_CODE = B.P_CODE
WHERE B.P_CODE IS NULL
```

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead and return the value(s) from `A`.

Comment: Why isn't the 2nd one working. What results do you get that are wrong? At a minimum, the 2nd query must give you all the rows from the [Race] table.

Comment: No, the second returns nothing. Is that because of the Where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a left join

```
Select A.* from [Table A] A 
left join [Table B] B on A.P_CODE = B.P_CODE
where B.P_CODE IS NULL
```

The left join gives you all rows in A regardless of whether or not there is a match in B. So the ones that have a null B.P_CODE aren't in B.,

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried you query and I still get no results.  Very curious.

Comment: Two things to try. Just do a `Select * from {table A]` to confirm that you get rows returned. If so, then try doing the Left Join query with `B.P_CODE = NULL` instead of IS NULL.

Comment: Select * from Table A returned 600 rows, but when I did the left join with B.P_Code = Null it returned nothing - 0 rows affected.

Comment: So does an inner join give you the 400 common rows?

Answer (score 1):

I just used another tool (Alteryx) to do a join in a more visible fashion.  It turns out my referential integrity had broken down and Table A had 200 duplicates.   So the result returned (zero rows) was in fact correct.